# Probability of waiting time at a signal

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

Let $W$ be the time you wait for the traffic light at an intersection turn GREEN, if it is RED. Suppose that you find that the light at the intersection is GREEN with probability $p = \frac{1}{4}$ (Since there is no wait, so $W = 0$). With probability $p' = 3/4$  you find that the light is RED.

Let $W$ be exponential random variable with rate $\lambda = 1/5$ : Assume that there is no traffic jam at the intersection and you pass the light as soon as it's GREEN. Compute:
a) C.D.F
b) E(W)

Comment: has anything been tried ?

Comment: We would love to solve YOUR problem rather than the homework problem you just copied and pasted. Write down what you have tried so far, and what you are not able to figure out.

Comment: I am not exactly sure which topic of the probability theory do I refer to if I have this sort of problem where you follow a probability distribution conditional on another event, for instance, in this case, it follows an exponential distribution with probability 3/4

Comment: @ShahzaibAli which topic of probability theory? Why, conditional probability/expectation/densities, of course!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(W)  &= \left[\dfrac{1}{4} \times 0\right] + \left[ \dfrac{3}{4}\mathbb{E}(W|\lambda)\right] \\
& = \dfrac{3}{4} \times \lambda^{-1} \tag{mean of an exponential r.v. is $\lambda^{-1}$} \\
& = \dfrac{15}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: are you sure about this? could you please elaborate

Comment: @ShahzaibAli what are you unsure of in this answer? Is it because you are not familiar with the law of total expectation?